# List <> Type for a RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written the follow method for a `RadioButtonList`, but I get the following error `"Type expected"` under the `List<>`

What type is expected here? I've tried a few options but just get errors under ListItem because I can't figure out the correct one to use?!

```
public void getPositionStatusList(List<> RadioButtonList)
{
    List<PositionStatus> PositionStatusList = new List<PositionStatus>();
    PositionStatusList = careersManager.GetListOfPositionStatus();

    foreach (PositionStatus PositionStatus in PositionStatusList)
    {
        string title = PositionStatus.StatusDescription;
        string value = PositionStatus.StatusId.ToString();
        RadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem(title, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you want  `getPositionStatusList(List<RadioButtonList> radioButtonList)`?

Comment: @Sergio I don't think so `RadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem(title, value));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public void getPositionStatusList(List<> RadioButtonList)
```

to

```
public void getPositionStatusList(List<RadioButton> RadioButtonList)
```

or

```
public void getPositionStatusList(RadioButtonList RadioButtonList)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `List<T>`, you have to provide the type of the elements that will be stored in the list. For example if you're expecting a list of strings, you should use `List<string>`. In your case you're expecting a list of radiobutton as a parameter, the event should look like:

```
public void getPositionStatusList(List<RadioButton> RadioButtonList)
{
}
```

Sidenote: use camelcase for methods, the name of your method should be `GetPositionStatusList`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I should have written ListBox.

Apologies.